# node wait for response from one GET request before triggering the next one

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am making two successive calls to an API using `node`.

Firstly, I make a `GET` request, following which I use data from the response to make the second `GET` request. I want to ensure the first `API` call has finished before triggering the second call.

I have tried using both node packages `request` / `request-promise` to make a server-side `GET` request to the Spotify API.

Initially, I was using `request` but just installed `request-promise`. Perhaps this is not necessary. Please see my code below. Can anyone spot any obvious mistake I am making? I expected it to work after [following this post.](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-node-js-request-module-tutorial/)

```
var request = require('request-promise');

request(url, function(error, response, body) {
  var body = JSON.parse(body);
  for (var i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
    test.push(body[i].url)
  }

}
res.send(req.body);
}).then(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    request(url2, function(error, response, body) {
      test2.push(body);
    });
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`request-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) for your issue is a good idea because promises are better equiped to handle async code than callbacks, especially when dealing with multiple requests and error handling.

However, your usage of the `request-promise` is incorrect. The callback-style you have here is the way [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) works but not promises.

The success callback in promises is passed into the `then` hook, not into the initial promise construction.

Additionally, the error isn't passed to the success (first) callback but is caught in the rejection (second) callback (or in the catch hook).

For the second request, you are actually trying to make multiple request, one for every url in the provided array. To ensure all those request are finished before proceeding, you should use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Here's how you'd structure your promises using `request-promise`.

```
request({ uri: url, json: true }) // this is how the docs for request-promise say you can request a json
  .then(function (json) { // accumulate array of urls and pass them along the promise chain
    var urls = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      urls.push(json[i].url)
    }
    return urls;
  })
  .then(function (urls) {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
      promises.push(request(urls[i])); // create a promise for each url and fire off the request
    }
    return Promise.all(promises); // continue down the chain once all promises (request) are resolved
  })
  .then(function (arrayOfResultsFromEachPreviousRequest) {
    // ...
  });
```

Using ES6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), you can reduce the code even further:

```
request({ url: url, json: true })
  .then(json => json.map(item => item.url))
  .then(urls => Promise.all(urls.map(url => request(url))))
  .then(arrayOfResultsFromEachPreviousRequest => {
    // ...
  });
```

---

If you want to use the callback-styled `request`, things would be much more painful, especially the second part that waits on multiple requests.

For comparison purposes, here's an approach using callback ([hell](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch2.md)) without error handling:

```
request.get({ url:url, json:true }, function(err, res, json) {
  var urls = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    urls.push(json[i].url)
  }
  makeRemainingRequests(urls, function(arrayOfResultsFromEachPreviousRequest) {
    // ...
  });
});

function makeRemainingRequests(urls, cb) {
  var results = new Array(urls.length).fill(false); // array holding the results of all requests
  for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    // wrap each request in an IIFE so we have a correct value of i
    (function(idx) {
      request(urls[idx], function(err, res, body) {
        results[idx] = body;
        // if all results obtained, call the callback
        if (results.every(function (res) { return !!res; })) {
          cb(results);
        }
      });
    })(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for a very thorough answer. code seems slightly bloated though :-S

Comment: I gave you an answer with the least amount of changes to your code and then one using ES6 which is basically 3 lines of code, not sure what's bloated about that :P. I even added a solution using callbacks which will show you how painful it would be if we didn't have promises :)

Comment: i really appreciate it.. i don't mean your code is bloated, just the method seems more verbose than i expected.

Comment: glad to help mate. Managing async code with callbacks gets deceptively difficult with seemingly small increase in complexity. That's why ES6 and beyond contains many awesome tools (such as promises) to handle this.